# How to fix this permission denied error when performing a gem update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to set up my first rails app which I've cloned from Heroku.

When I do a `gem update` I get the following:

```
gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating bigdecimal
Fetching: bigdecimal-1.2.7.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/grant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.7
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `rvm` or `gem` as root accidentally at some point?
If so then this might fix your problem:

```
sudo chown -R grant.grant /Users/grant/.rvm
```

It will recursively make you the owner of all files in the `.rvm` folder, because if you ran those Ruby commands as root at one point or another, then `root` will be the owner of some files, and `gem` can't write to folders owned by `root` when running under yourself (user `grant`).

Comment: Yes I probably did. What would the command be if the user was foo? sudo chown -R foo.foo /Users/foo/.rvm

Comment: @spuggy Yes. `chown -R username.username`. So `foo.foo` in your example is correct.

Comment: @spuggy However be VERY careful with that command because it will recursively change all permissions. You can mess up your computer if you'd do for example "`sudo chown -R foo.foo /`". That would change the owner of EVERY file on the whole computer. So always check that you have the correct path before pressing enter.